# Download file using token based API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, token

I'm creating a web application with **Vue.js**(front end) + **Laravel**(back end) and I structured the whole app to communicate with the back end through api routes. The requests pass through a middleware for authentication using a token (passport in Laravel). At some point I need to download some files, but I wouldn't know how to make it happend because I have no way to identificate or authenticate the user though web routes. I could send byte data from the API through an ajax request but then it would be difficult to make the user download the file from the javascript (at least it would be hard to make things work on every browser).

So what's the best approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently had to solve this problem.

First we sent the file stream via ajax request and then download the file via HTML5 file API, but it caused a lot of problems for files > 5MB.

The solution that we implemented at the end, and sounds best is to create a temporary file URL with some temporary token, for that file to be downloaded. With an expiration like 5 minutes or whatever suits your need. On your API call send that new URL and open in new tab or download or any other thing you want to do.

EDIT: 
We were using Amazon s3 for storage so the authentication was not a problem, but you will need to make changes to authentication layer to allow temp URL access without token to reach your temp file handling controller.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. What changes should i make for the authentication layer to allow temp URL access without token?

Comment: In your case I guess you don't need to make any change, just create a new route "/fileDownload" and don't specify auth middleware on it. I'm not familiar with Laravel so can't tell exactly. But seeing from documentation you specify middle ware like this,

Route::get('/user', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth:api');

just don't do this for your temp url route